# How to put values in last row if the value in certain range is certain word using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a range of cells, from M to AL and they display values "True" or "False" for certain data. I need a code that goes trough that range row by row and when finds a value "False" puts value 1 in AN column and colors that row. This is my code so far:

```
Set r = Sheet7.Range("W:AL")
For i = 5 To RowCount
With r.Cells(i)
If .Value = "False" Then
    .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 15773610
    Cells(i, "AN").Value = 1
End If
End With
Next i
```

But it doesn't work. I'm probably missing something but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why VBA? Use a Formula in AN that if any False in that row, then 1, else nothing. And then color the row using Conditional Formating

Comment: Also, in your question you say *...from M to AL...* and your code says `"W:AL"`. Which one is the right one?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns M to AL is correct, my mistake.. How do I write the formula for that?

Answer (score 1):

My example is with less data, Just adapt the formulas to your needs.
Also, please note my Excel is in Spanish, but I'll translate formulas.

For this answer, we will use [Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

My data is just `A1:C17`. Some cells contain a number and others contain a False value (False in spanish is False, check image):

[image]

Ok, first step would be in column AN to use an Array Formula to show a 1 value if any cell in the row is False, and nothing if not. In my case, I put that formula in column D. I used `=IF(A1:C1=FALSE;1;"")`. Drag it down.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: When you type this formula, do not press enter. You have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, to make it an array formula. If you don't do it like this, it will fail. After applying formula, I get this results in column D:

[image]

Note that only rows with a False value raise a 1 in Column D. Rest of cells are blank.

Second step, the conditional formatting. Just create a rule that says that if D cell = 1 then background color is red. Remember to create the rule with relative references (blocking just the column, not the row) to make it work. My formula in the rule is `=IF($D1=1;TRUE;FALSE)` and the rule is like this:

[image]

And final result is like this. As you can see, it colors all the row if value in cell D is 1. If not, it does nothing:

[image]

Hope this helps. Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help, but for some reason this worked only partly for me. I figured out a solution using VBA.

Comment: I don't know the reason, that's why I said "for some reason". I would gladly let you know what it was if I knew.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me so I hope it'll be helpful to someone else.

```
Set r = Sheet7.Range("M:AL")
For i = 5 To RowCount
With r.Cells(i)
If .Value = "False" Then
    .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 15773610
End If
End With
Next i
For i = 5 To RowCount
If Sheet7.Cells(i, "AL").Interior.Color = 15773610 Then
    Cells(i, "AN").Value = 1
End If
Next I
```